# Double click event in MVVM Foundation

Tags: wpf, mvvm, mvvm-foundation

I've seen several methods for handling this across several libraries but I want to know the best way to do this, specifically with MVVM Foundation.  I'm trying to capture double click for list item. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's "the best way" but I've been using Attached Behaviors for this. I can provide some sample code if you like or were you just interested in what the best way was?

Example of Attached Behavior for this can be found here:
 [WPF/MVVM - how to handle double-click on TreeViewItems in the ViewModel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4497825/wpf-mvvm-how-to-handle-double-click-on-treeviewitems-in-the-viewmodel/4498006#4498006)