# Capture DoubleClick in DataGrid 

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I have a WPF/MVVM application with a DataGrid on a window. I want to call a method when the user double clicks on a row in the DataGrid.

How can I bind the DblClick event of the DataGrid to my ViewModel?

Comment: See this post [WPF/MVVM - how to handle double-click on TreeViewItems in the ViewModel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4497825/wpf-mvvm-how-to-handle-double-click-on-treeviewitems-in-the-viewmodel/4498006#4498006)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I liked the last solution using the CodeBehind to link to the Edit Command. Much simpler solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer to use [AttachedCommand Behaviors](http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/12/13/attachedcommandbehavior-v2-aka-acb/), which allow you to attach a Command to just about any UI Event

For example,

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
    <Setter Property="local:CommandBehavior.Event" Value="MouseDoubleClick" />
    <Setter Property="local:CommandBehavior.Command" Value="{Binding MyDoubleClickCommand" />
    <Setter Property="local:CommandBehavior.CommandParameter" Value="{Binding }" />
</Style>
```