# How to change data template when item clicked?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have `ItemsControl` with `DataTemplate` that looks like this:

[image]

I want to achieve effect when user clicks on item - it expands vertically and shows more info.

The only way I'm thinking is to change it to `ListBox` and create 2 `DataTemplates` for selected and regular view?

But I'd rather register click on `Grid` and flip property on my VM to expand this box. Is there any way to register when user clicks on `Grid` MVVM way?

Comment: Do you want to be able to expand multiple items at once?  If so, how would the user collapse the expanded items?  ItemsControl isn't a Selector so it doesn't register a SelectedItem.  You're best using a ListBox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an attached behavior for the `MouseDown` event.
See the following question: [WPF/MVVM - how to handle double-click on TreeViewItems in the ViewModel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4497825/wpf-mvvm-how-to-handle-double-click-on-treeviewitems-in-the-viewmodel)

In your case it would look like this

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ...}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <Setter Property="commandBehaviors:MouseDown.Command"
                    Value="{Binding YourItemClickCommand}"/>
            <Setter Property="commandBehaviors:MouseDown.CommandParameter"
                    Value="{Binding}"/>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <!-- ... -->
</ItemsControl>
```

*MouseDown*

```
public class MouseDown
{
    public static DependencyProperty CommandProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Command",
                                            typeof(ICommand),
                                            typeof(MouseDown),
                                            new UIPropertyMetadata(CommandChanged));

    public static DependencyProperty CommandParameterProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("CommandParameter",
                                            typeof(object),
                                            typeof(MouseDown),
                                            new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

    public static void SetCommand(DependencyObject target, ICommand value)
    {
        target.SetValue(CommandProperty, value);
    }

    public static void SetCommandParameter(DependencyObject target, object value)
    {
        target.SetValue(CommandParameterProperty, value);
    }
    public static object GetCommandParameter(DependencyObject target)
    {
        return target.GetValue(CommandParameterProperty);
    }

    private static void CommandChanged(DependencyObject target, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Control control = target as Control;
        if (control != null)
        {
            if ((e.NewValue != null) && (e.OldValue == null))
            {
                control.MouseDown += OnMouseDown;
            }
            else if ((e.NewValue == null) && (e.OldValue != null))
            {
                control.MouseDown -= OnMouseDown;
            }
        }
    }

    private static void OnMouseDown(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Control control = sender as Control;
        ICommand command = (ICommand)control.GetValue(CommandProperty);
        object commandParameter = control.GetValue(CommandParameterProperty);
        command.Execute(commandParameter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I'm following the question properly but is it something like the DataGrid RowDetails feature that you are seeking? It shows a detail panel for selected items:

http://wpftutorial.net/DataGrid.html#rowDetails