# Attach command to tree view children - different for nested children

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, attachedbehaviors

I'm using code from here: [WPF/MVVM - how to handle double-click on TreeViewItems in the ViewModel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4497825/wpf-mvvm-how-to-handle-double-click-on-treeviewitems-in-the-viewmodel), from accepted answer. My xaml is like this:

```
<TreeView CommandBehaviors:MouseDoubleClick.Command="{Binding ConnectServer}" CommandBehaviors:MouseDoubleClick.CommandParameter="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" 
                                  Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" DockPanel.Dock="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ServerItems, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="CommandBehaviors:MouseDoubleClick.Command" Value="{Binding ConnectDb}"/>
            <Setter Property="CommandBehaviors:MouseDoubleClick.CommandParameter" Value="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
        </Style>
    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Databases}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

Attached command from Style tag does not work, and it should't since there is already a command attached on the TreeView tag level. What I'm trying to do is to execute one command for top level children, and another for lower level children. How do I do that?

EDIT:

So, as Viv suggested - how do I check if treeviewitem is a root node?

Comment: remove the attached properties off the `TreeView` and add a `Style.Trigger` that checks if the current `TreeViewItem` is the root and accordingly applies the attached properties to what you currently have in the `TreeView`

Comment: I actually have no idea on how to do that, could you please give me some example code? You can post an answer and if it works, I'll accept it.

Comment: I mean - checking it like that: `<Trigger Property="IsRootNode">` doesn't work = there's no IsRootNode property, so should I write this on my own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like:

```
<Window.Resources>
  <CommandBehaviors:IsRootNodeConverter x:Key="IsRootNodeConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
  <TreeView>
    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="CommandBehaviors:MouseDoubleClick.Command"
                Value="{Binding ConnectDb}" />
        <Setter Property="CommandBehaviors:MouseDoubleClick.CommandParameter"
                Value="{Binding Path=SelectedItem,
                                RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground"
                Value="Black" />
        <Style.Triggers>
          <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=.,
                                          RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                                          Converter={StaticResource IsRootNodeConverter}}"
                        Value="True">
            <Setter Property="CommandBehaviors:MouseDoubleClick.Command"
                    Value="{Binding ConnectServer}" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground"
                    Value="Tomato" />
          </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
      <HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        <!--<TreeViewItem>-->
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
        <!--</TreeViewItem>-->
      </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    <TreeViewItem Header="1">
      <TreeViewItem Header="A" />
      <TreeViewItem Header="B">
        <TreeViewItem Header="AA" />
        <TreeViewItem Header="AB" />
        <TreeViewItem Header="AC" />
      </TreeViewItem>
      <TreeViewItem Header="C" />
    </TreeViewItem>
  </TreeView>
</Grid>
```

and converter:

```
class IsRootNodeConverter : IValueConverter
{
  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
    TreeViewItem item = value as TreeViewItem;
    if (item == null || item.Parent == null)
      return false;
    return !Object.ReferenceEquals(value.GetType(), item.Parent.GetType());
  }

  public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
    throw new NotImplementedException();
  }
}
```

I intentionally left out the `CommandBehaviors:MouseDoubleClick.CommandParameter` from the `Style` `Trigger` as it does not seem to change from default. Just added a `Foreground` property for testing, You can delete that too.

Comment: I can't get this to work (not only the commands are not run, but even the foreground properties are not set) - maybe it's because my items are being added dynamically?

Comment: works fine for me. You could maybe tell me how your testing it?  http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30994/wpf-treeview-bugfix